# not able to read xml in C# xml to linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

HI i am trying to read xml file but i am not able to get the elemets 
here is my sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <title>Read xml file</title>
        <link href=""></link>
        <updated>2014-01-06T10:32:04.230060</updated>
        <author><name>rss</name></author>

        <entry>
            <title>abc: Watching &#34;Mary Tyler Moore.&#34; Every character is drinking Scotch. #The70s </title>
            <link href="http://RobertOSimonson/status/417858586618781697"></link>
            <id>/RobertOSimonson/status/417858586618781697</id>
            <updated>2013-12-30T19:23:00Z</updated>
            <published>2013-12-30T19:23:00Z</published>
            <summary>Watching &#34;Mary Tyler Moore.&#34; Every character is drinking Scotch. #The70s </summary>
        </entry>

        <entry>
            <title>abc: Galliano makes very appropriate cameo in the &#39;70s-set &#34;American Hustle.&#34; #AmericanHustle </title>
            <link href="http://RobertOSimonson/status/417511925258272768"></link>
            <id>/RobertOSimonson/status/417511925258272768</id>
            <updated>2013-12-29T20:26:00Z</updated>
            <published>2013-12-29T20:26:00Z</published>
            <summary>Galliano makes very appropriate cameo in the &#39;70s-set &#34;American Hustle.&#34; #AmericanHustle </summary>
        </entry>
</feed>
```

and in my C# code i am trying like this

```
var posts = (from p in rssFeed.Root.Elements("entry")
             select new
             {
                 Title = p.Element("title").Value,
                 Link = p.Element("link").Value,
             }).ToList();

foreach (var post in posts)
{
    Response.Write(post.Title + "<br>");
}
```

Please Suggest what i am doing wrong. i want to read what is inside 
Thanks

Comment: Your XML sample isn't valid, you're missing the closing `</feed>`

Comment: Edited it is there now.. i didnt add it in the question

Comment: is there any error? exception? what is the problem?

Comment: NO the page just comes blank.. nothing appears and no error

Comment: is there anything in posts when you debug?

Comment: Nope the post object is coming empty.. so i thought it is because i have not wrote the query well enough

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.Net, just linq to xml

Comment: Also, a tip: put code like this in a console app or (better yet) a unit test to debug it, instead of trying to debug it through ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the xml namespace in your queries:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var posts = (from p in rssFeed.Root.Elements(ns + "entry")
             select new
             {
                 Title = p.Element(ns + "title").Value,
                 Link = p.Element(ns + "link").Value,
             }).ToList();

foreach (var post in posts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(post.Title);
}
```

Check out the linq to xml samples for C# here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397976.aspx

Comment: Perfect i have a Response Object now :)